# Ribbon Combobox Spacing and Alignment

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, ribbon, spacing

I have two comboboxes, one beneath the other, on my ribbon with different lengths of texts. This makes the spacing uneven and I would like to correct that and hopefully allow more space between the two as well. Are there any easy ways to this or is it a limitation of MFC?

Current situation:

[image: Current]

Ideal situation:

[image: Ideal]

Comment: Care to show the code you're using?

Comment: No code, just using the ribbon editor in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I was able to accomplish what you want by setting *two* properties for the panel:

- *Center Column Vertical* = **true**
- *Justify Columns* = **true**

The ribbon displayed correctly as you wanted when I tested it in Visual Studio.  However, it did not display correctly initially.  After starting the application, I had to change the style to any other style before the change would take effect.  I think that's because of the tight coupling of the **Workspace** settings in the registry.